# unicode as hex in VIM

Tags: vim, unicode, hex

I was reading this article on unicode - http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/unicode

To understand the concept better, in VIM I saved the unicode character 'ഒ' U+0D12. When I switched to hex mode (using :%!xxd command) I see the following:

0000000: e0b4 920a                                ....

\0a is the ending \n . But  the other hex values doesn't make any sense to me. Can anyone throw some light on this?

Comment: What you're seeing are the three bytes in which "ഒ" has been encoded in UTF-8 encoding. Please read any basic Unicode tutorial such as [this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), [this](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars.html), or maybe one of [these](http://www.unicode.org/standard/tutorial-info.html), or ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `U+0D12` is the unicode code point of ഒ.
- `E0 B4 92` is the hexadecimal representation of the three bytes composing ഒ as encoded in UTF-8.
- `xxd` doesn't know or care about unicode code points so it does what it's supposed to do by default: it shows the hexadecimal values of every byte you give to it.

If you are curious, hitting `ga` in Vim shows the value of the character under your cursor in various formats:

```
<ഒ> 3346, Hex 0d12, Octal 6422
```

and `g8` shows its hexadecimal value:

```
e0 b4 92
```

If you are *very* curious, `:%!xxd -b` shows the binary values of those bytes:

```
11100000 10110100 10010010
```

Answer (score 3):

If you've expected to see `0D12`, that's just the Unicode *codepoint*. Your Vim buffer is encoded in UTF-8, which uses a variable number of bytes to encode the characters: The newline is a single byte `0a`, whereas the codepoint is encoded by 3 bytes. As glts commented, there are several tutorials out there to learn these important distinctions.

You can save the buffer in another encoding, e.g. via `:w ++enc=ucs2`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: And there's the basic multilingual plane vs. the extended ones, and so many fine points to make. I tried to keep the explanation simple, and for most practical matters (i.e. commonly used symbols like Cyrillic and Chinese), the 16-bit range is enough.

Comment: That does not make it any more correct. (And no, none of those things needs explaination here; all you have to do is not *mislead* by superfluously mentioning "16-bit")

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Okay, I've edited it out, was just a side note, anyway. Maybe this only shows that I'm an old geezer who experienced the time when the Unicode people actually believed that all symbols would fit into 16 bit :-)